# Convert response stream to XML

Tags: c#, xml, rest, stream

I sent an XML  post to demo API and the response comes back as a stream of XML something like this:

```
API=3CProductData&XML=%3CProductData+Name%3D%22NameTest%22%3E%0D%0A++%3CId%3EXXXXXXXXX%3C%2FId%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FProductData%3E
```

I'm guessing this is what stream look like and my goal is to take that response and store it inside a new ProductData Object here is what I have done so far:

```
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        // as an xml: deserialise into your own object or parse as you wish
        StreamReader respStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        string receivedResponse = respStream.ReadToEnd();

        XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProductData));

        ProductData product = (ProductData) x.Deserialize(new StringReader(receivedResponse));
        Console.WriteLine("Node1: " + product.Id.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Node2: " + product.Name);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The Error Comes back with System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in XML document (0, 0).'
XmlException: Root element is missing.

Comment: Is that your actual response body? Or is that data from a querystring?

Comment: its the Querystring shouldn't that be the response as well

Comment: @Jesse de Wit also i customized the response to give me an XML but still same issue?

Comment: That is some bad XML though.  The Name node does not close itself.  You're going to have to manually handle this response I'm afraid.

Comment: The querystring is part of the url (of the request). The http response message consists of a statuscode, headers and a response body. Post the statuscode and response body here and we may help. (read the response body as a string and inspect it in the debugger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two different solutions.

```
    public ProductData TestFunction()
    {
        ProductData result = new ProductData();

        string apiResponse = "API=3CProductData&XML=%3CProductData+Name%3D%22NameTest%22%3E%0D%0A++%3CId%3EXXXXXXXXX%3C%2FId%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FProductData%3E";
        string xml = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(apiResponse.Substring(apiResponse.IndexOf("XML=") + 4));
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.LoadXml(xml);

        XmlNode newNode = document.DocumentElement;

        // Name is actually an attribute on the ProductData
        result.Name = ((XmlAttribute)newNode.Attributes["Name"]).InnerText;

        // Id is an actual node
        result.ID = ((XmlNode)newNode.FirstChild).InnerText;


        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProductData));
            result = (ProductData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return result;
    }

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("ProductData")]
public class ProductData
{
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

There is one very fragile part of this code, and I didn't spend a lot of time trying to do handle it.  The XML is not really well-formed in my opinion, so you're going to have to substring after the `XML=` which is why I added the +4 at the end of that.  Probably a smoother way to do it, but again the issue is really with converting the XML.  Since the XML is really simple, you can just target the values via SelectSingleNode.  If you want to go the StreamReader route, you need to make sure your class/properties have the attributes set up (i.e. [XmlRoot("Productdata")])

Comment: Ok, when I did this it returns "Root element is missing."  any suggestions

Comment: Can you post your updated code with my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the part `API=3CProductData&XML=` in your string and then, decode your part XML

Look at this [code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OyNuGe) working :

```
string strRegex = @"<ProductData Name=""NameTest"">\r\n  <Id>XXXXXXXXX</Id>\r\n</ProductData>";
ProductData result = null;
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(strRegex))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProductData));
    result = (ProductData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: I can't control the stream and what it looks like.